# How to upload a text string directly to Windows Azure Blob from the browser using javascript

Tags: javascript, api, rest, azure, blob

I would like to upload from a web browser a text/html string as an Azure blob  directly to Azure storage (without first going thru the Azure VM/webserver) using browser side javascript. From my research, I understand that one can use Azure REST API + Shared Access Signatures to achieve this from a Silverlight client or thru an MVC 3 view. ( here is the link for controls using SilverLight/MVC3 : http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlight/Silverlight-Azure-Blob-3b773e26#content). I also found a library for uploading using server side javascript with Node.JS https://github.com/jpgarcia/waz-storage-js .

My question is how would one upload a text string to an Azure blob using only browser side javascript and html and SAS  (without using Silverlight or MVC) and do so directly to Azure without going thru the web server? How would one pass the string value to the Azure rest api call ( would it accept a JSON string?) ? I looked at the MSDN REST api examples but it was not clear to me how you would pass a text string to be uploaded. Can anyone help with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this can be done. Unless the web page is being hosted from the same blob storage domain, this would be a cross-domain call, which isn't allowed (unless CORS headers are set, which they aren't for blob storage).

In addition, uploading to a blob requires an HTTP PUT request, and I believe most browsers only allow POST and GET.

**UPDATE**

See comments below, but it looks like some browsers do allow PUT requests. As noted, the same-origin policy can be defeated by serving the original page from the same blob storage account. In that case, the code would look something like this (using jQuery):

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'PUT',
    data: 'Hello, World!',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}
}).success(function () {
    console.log('Saved successfully.');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, Steve. Of the two problems you mention, #1 cross domain can be overcome in my case as we can host the web page in the same blob storage domain so the rest api call would update the same blob in the same domain. For #2, I was think more along the lines of an AJAX call to the Azure REST api in which case I believe PUT should be supported (for ajax). Given these two possible workarounds, can the problem be solved?  Can the string be passed as JSON parameter to the Azure REST api?

Comment: After searching around, it looks like you may be right that PUT requests are allowed. As to the body, a blob PUT request just has raw data in the body, so don't JSON encode (or form encode). Just put the text in the body directly.

Comment: For what it's worth, jQuery's `$.ajax` documentation mentions that you can try to use PUT but that it's not supported in all browsers. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/.

Comment: Re "just put data in the body directly" - being that I am somewhat new to the Azure Rest API, could you please provide an example of what the code for such a REST call would look like using say Jquery .ajax ?

Comment: Thanks @smarx, as a clarification, would the url in the code correspond to azurebloburl+"?"+SASstring ? for example something like the following   url https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/containername/filename.html?sv=2012-02-12&st=2009-02-09T08%3a49Z&se=2009-02-10T08%3a49Z&
sr=c&sp=w&si=YWJjZGVmZw%3d%3d&sig=Rcp6gQRfV7WDlURdVTqCa%2bqEArnfJxDgE%2bKH3TCChIs%3d    (using the SAS example from msdn)

Answer (score 0):

You can upload from the client without touching the MVC site using JavaScript, I have written a blog post with an example on how to do this
http://blog.dynabyte.se/2013/10/09/uploading-directly-to-windows-azure-blob-storage-from-javascript/
the [code is at GitHub](https://github.com/MartinWa/BlobUploader)

It is based on [Gaurav Mantris post](http://gauravmantri.com/2013/02/16/uploading-large-files-in-windows-azure-blob-storage-using-shared-access-signature-html-and-javascript/) and works by hosting the JavaScript on the Blob Storage itself.