# How to use .NET using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, .net

I am new to JavaScript. My requirement is that I want to be able to use .NET through JavaScript -- and there should not be browser lock in. I should be able to run it either with Internet Explorer or Edge or Chrome. I am just trying to understand exactly what I need for this? I even heard that various flavors of JavaScript are out there. So exactly what type of JavaScript I need for this? Please provide some pointers.

Answer (score 0):

it will be better if you explain what kind of .net technology you are trying to implement at back end. for example you want to call server side code from java script ,

Regarding flavors of JavaScript it will be good if you start with ES 5 or 6

[enter link description here](http://es6-features.org/#Constants)

Comment: Basically I need something in which I can call Azure API , I want to build Azure website (azure app) that will retrieve information from Azure Data Factory.

Comment: this Might Helep 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17486966/can-i-use-javascript-call-the-azure-management-rest-api

If you are interested in Node.js this might help you to start.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-api-nodejs-api-app/